# Using Multiprocessing in a Time and Memory Efficient Way

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing

I have a problem and am running out of ideas, so I'm hoping someone has a better idea.

I am trying to run an optimization in python over millions of data points. I have a function `calculate(data)`, which receives a huge array `data` and returns an array of the same size `results`. The calculations are fairly simple, but they need to be made for each entry in `results` using several entries in `data` and unfortunately can't be vectorized. Due to dimensionality reasons the size of `data` and `results` is massive and can't be reduced.
Due to the sheer number of calculations this can take several days to calculate.

Therefore I started using `multiprocessing`, which improves the speed significantly. The way I implemented this was by cutting `results` into chunks, giving each core the full (required) `data` array and the task to calculate its individual chunk of the whole `results` array and returning them to merge them after. (using `pool.apply_async(func, (data,))`)

As the size of `data` increased further however, I started getting memory errors. From my analysis, this is because each core has its individual `data` array, meaning I have the original `1 + # of cores` copies of `data` in my RAM. To cut down on this I figured I would try to use a manager with a proxy dictionary for `data` that each core can then access. (using `data_shared = manager.dict(data)`) Unfortunately this has turned out to be incredibly slow which is presumably why it's not recommended.

Is there an obvious solution to this that I missed? I am very grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using a list of integers.

This code just breaks up an array of 1000 integers from 0, 1, 2, ... 999 into chunk sizes of 10 ending up with 1000 / 10 = 100 chunks and creates 100 lists from these chunks. These chunks along with its starting index are submitted to a worker that sums the elements of the lists and returns back the starting index and sum, which is then used to compute the grand total. Here the starting index is not being used to calculate the grand total but in another context it could be useful.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array
import itertools


def init_pool(arr):
    global data
    data = arr


def my_worker(tpl):
    index, results_chunk = tpl
    # sum items from results_chunk and data array:
    data_index = index
    the_sum = 0
    for item in results_chunk:
        the_sum += item + data[data_index]
        data_index += 1
    return index, the_sum


def get_chunks(arr, size):
    index = 0
    it = iter(arr)
    while True:
        x = tuple(itertools.islice(it, size))
        if not x:
            return
        yield index, list(x)
        index += size


# required for Windows and other platforms that do not have a fork() call:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [x for x in range(1000, 2000)]
    data_sum = sum(data)
    arr = Array('i', data, lock=False)
    results = [x for x in range(1000)]
    results_sum = sum(results)
    print('Excpected total sum =', data_sum + results_sum)
    with Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(arr,)) as pool:
        total = 0
        for index, the_sum in pool.imap_unordered(my_worker, get_chunks(results, 10), 3):
            total += the_sum
        print('Actual total sum =', total)
```

Prints:

```
Excpected total sum = 1999000
Actual total sum = 1999000
```

Comment: hey, thank you for your suggestion :) I have some questions: does get_chunks() get passed to each worker or only its yields? If it does get passed, doesn't that require passing the data array as well? If it doesn't get passed, how would that work for my example? The problem I have is that I don't know which entries of the data array will be needed in the calculate() function as that is calculated in the function.

Comment: **Does get_chunks() get passed to each worker or only its yields?** Only what it yields, which are sub-lists of the larger list. The code would be suitable for breaking up and submitting your `results` work -- I mislabeled it `data` -- sorry about that. If you do not want copies of your `data` in each address space, then using a managed structure (why not an Array rather than a dict?) is the only way I know. Perhaps someone else knows otherwise.

Comment: If your calculations (or most of them) can be done using a C-Language package such as `numpy`, then instead of using multiprocessing you could use multithreading and still get significant parallelism since there would no longer be as much contention for the Global Interpreter Lock and, of course, everything would be in one address space. Plus you get the speedup from using `C`.

Comment: After I made my last comment I knew something was amiss. If you use a non-managed multiprocessing structure such as a `multiprocessing.Array` or `multiprocessing.dict`, it is implemented in shared memory and there should only be one copy. See updated answer where I have `results` as chunked pieces implemented as plain lists that are passed and `data`, which is a `multiprocessing.Array` in shared memory without a lock since it is read only. The `results` before being chunked is the same size as `data` and the objective is to sum all the elements together (in a convoluted way).

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry for getting back to you so late. I implemented your suggestion and after finally shooting down some bugs, I can confirm, that it works perfectly. I didn't time how fast exactly each access of the array is compared to what I had tried before, but the extra time delay is not noticable, let's put it that way. Thank you very much for your help, you really saved me! :)